# Converting sums to matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I am able to transform basic sums to vector/matrix equations.

But now I have something like:

$$
c_{p,q} = \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{r=1}^R \sum_{s=1}^S e_n x_{n-q-s,p} \cdot h_{r,s} \cdot g_r \cdot y^*_{n-s,r} \cdot y_{n-s,r} \quad, \qquad p=\{1,\dots,P\}, q=\{1,\dots,Q\}
$$

I don't see the forest for the trees!

The result should be a $P\cdot Q$ vector (if it's easier, can be a $P\times Q$ or $Q\times P$ matrix as well).

How do I do stuff like that? Are there general rules/patterns which I could follow?

I started off taking $e_n$ out and creating a matrix A:

$$
\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{e}
$$

where $\mathbf{A}$ is an $PQ \times N$ matrix. But now I am stuck factorizing matrix $\mathbf{A}$ ....

Comment: How $y^*$ is related to $y$?

Comment: it's the complex conjungate. Edit: Technically it is but it's more complicated. It's better to treat them separately because they treat the "r" differently

Comment: So the result is complex? Because $y^∗_{n−s,r}⋅y_{n−s,r}\ne y_{n−s,r}^*⋅y_{r,n-s}=|y_{n-s,r}|^2$

Comment: In the end the result will be complex, yes. But at the moment I am just struggling at the basic problem of how to factor matrices out of sums ;-) So in the very end it will be: $y^*_{n-s,r}=(y^*[n-s])^{(r-3)/2}$ and $y_{n-s,r}=y^{(r+1)/2}[n-s]$ where $(\cdot)^*$ denotes the complex conjungate